# JMeter loop then delay

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a JMeter script with just 1 thread, where the following happens:

- Repeat

  - Loop 20 times
  - Send JMS request
  - Wait 2 minutes
- End repeat

However, I seem unable to get the setup correct for the constant timer. Wherever I put it, it doesn't seem to quite do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a Test Action Sampler.

Setup should be as follows:

- Simple Controller

  - Loop Controller
  - Test Action Sampler

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the following steps:

- Thread count set loop count 20

  - Your sampler
  - Constant time 20000